# Angular NgRx dispatching action method

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

So we have this ordinary effect `doSomething`. What is the *official* way to dispatch another action, named `doSomethingElse`? The documentation doesn't really say anything about the right way. In the end there might not be much difference, yet I don't really like the fact I could use `dispatch: false` in like 95% of my codebase.

**Dispatching action by using `dispatch: false`:**

```
doSomething$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActions.doSomething),
  map(() => AuthActions.doSomethingElse())
));

doSomethingElse$ = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.doSomethingElse),
    tap(() => console.log('it works!'))
  ),
{ dispatch: false });
```

**Dispatching action without `dispatch: false`:**

```
doSomething$ = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.doSomething),
    tap(() => {
      this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.doSomethingElse());
    })
  ),
{ dispatch: false });

doSomethingElse$ = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.doSomethingElse),
    tap(() => console.log('it works!'))
  ),
{ dispatch: false });
```

Both solutions work, yet I am not sure which is the correct way of using NgRx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one is not recommended.

The following code would complain if you **didn't** map to an action whereas putting `{ dispatch: false }` removes this check and should only be used for *side effects* like navigation, setting localStorage etc.

```
doSomething$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActions.doSomething),
  map(() => AuthActions.doSomethingElse())
));
```

Your example isn't clear on why two actions are needed where one would do.

If you want a general action logger the following will work:

```
/**
 * Log all actions in the console
 */

export function logger(
  reducer: ActionReducer<RootStoreState.State>
): ActionReducer<RootStoreState.State> {
  return (state, action) => {
    const result = reducer(state, action);
    if (action.type.startsWith("[")) { <----FILTER TO ONLY USER CREATED ACTIONS (i.e. not router)---------
      console.groupCollapsed(action.type);
      console.log("prev state", state);
      console.log("action", action);
      console.log("next state", result);
      console.groupEnd();
    }

    return result;
  };
}
```

and in *app.module.ts*

```
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = !environment.production
  ? [logger]
  : [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot(ROOT_REDUCERS, {
      metaReducers, <--------------------------------------KEY LINE-----------
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateSerializability: true,
        strictActionSerializability: true
      }
    }),
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry about my example, I might have not been clear enough; the console.log part is just a placeholder for something that could be anything else instead. The point is, should I use `dispatch: false` in such situations where I am actually dispatching another action and which is not a side effect (I think you already answered this question, though :) )?

Comment: @Eyho yes, only use `dispatch: false` for effects that are only doing side effects. It also makes it easier to look at an effect and know it's purpose (map to another action /  side effect)

Answer (score -1):

I will put it in old style because I didnt migrate yet to new way of ngrx but its also the same.

Actions.ts

```
export enum AuthActionTypes {
    SIGNUP = '[AUTH] SIGNUP',
    SIGNUP_SUCCESS = '[AUTH] SIGNUP_SUCCESS',
}

export class Signup implements Action {
    readonly type = AuthActionTypes.SIGNUP;
    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}
export class SignupSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = AuthActionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS;
}

export type AuthActions =
    Signup |
    SignupSuccess;
```

Effect

````
@Effect()
    signup$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActionTypes.SIGNUP),
        map((action: Signup) => action.payload),
        map((payload) => {
              // whatever
            return new SignupSuccess(); // this come from AuthActions inner // action.ts, you are dispaching SignupSuccess();
        }),

@Effect()
    signupSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS),
        map((action: Signup) => action.payload),
        map((payload) => {
              // whatever
            return new XAction(); 
        }),
```
````